# Which Wires to Wrap Anti-Rodent Tape With?

Tags: honda, electrical, preventive-maintenance, wire

I am planning to wrap some of the wires in my Honda CRV/Accord's 
engine bay with anti-rodent electrical tape.

Which wires should I wrap **and** which ones should I NOT wrap?

Are there other parts that I should protect?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the ones you don't want to replace, don't wrap the ones that you'd like to replace. I personally don't like to replace factory wiring, so I'd wrap anything the rodents may possibly reach.

I'd also think about protecting the smaller vacuum hoses.